# Finding a tricky moment generating function

Tags: integration, statistics, moment-generating-functions

I have the probability density function 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\beta} e^{-(x-\theta)/\beta}$$ where $x > \theta$, $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, $\beta > 0$.

I am trying to find the moment generating function $M_{X}(t)$. I tried 
\begin{align*}
M_{X}(t) &= E(e^{Xt}) \\
&= \frac{1}{\beta} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{xt} \cdot e^{-(x-\theta)/\beta} \ dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\beta} \left[ \frac{1}{t-\frac{1}{\beta}} e^{xt - \frac{x+\theta}{\beta}}\right] ^{\infty}_{-\infty}
\end{align*}

But then I don't really think I can evaluate this, so I'm not sure if I've taken the wrong approach but can't seem to think of any other way. This isn't a homework problem, rather an exam review problem. I know that my desired answer is $\dfrac{e^{t \theta}}{1-\beta t}$, $t < \frac{1}{\beta}$.

Comment: The integration limits are incorrect: since density vanishes for $x\le \theta$, the lower integration limit is $\theta$.

Comment: @zhoraster Oh right, thanks. Wouldn't the upper bound still be $\infty$ though? After which it doesn't look evaluate-able?

Comment: For suitable $t$ the antiderivative dies at $\infty$.  Another possible approach is that $X=Y+\theta$ where $Y$ is nice exponential. So $E(e^{tX})=E(e^{t\theta}e^{tY})$, and you may know the mgf of the exponential.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm trying to grasp your comment, but I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: AndréNicolas is suggesting evaluating the integral via the subsitution $x=y+\theta$.

Comment: Apart from constant terms in front, the antiderivative is $\exp[-x(1/\beta-t)+\theta/\beta]$. If $1/\beta-t\gt 0$, this has limit $0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas right right, because we need the moment generating function to be finite. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. That's where the restriction $t\lt 1/\beta$ of your post comes from.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yeah it didn't strike me as obvious to _make_ the restriction in order to have a finite moment generating function. In the future I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: It is fairly common that an mgf is only defined for a restricted range of values of $t$. As long as that range includes an interval about $t=0$, things are fine.